# pcntl_fork() returning, Fatal error: Call to undefined function pcntl_fork()

Tags: php, fork, command-line-interface, pcntl, undefined-function

I'm trying to fork a command line run XAMPP php process using pcntl_fork(). When I run the command below:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if($pid == -1){
    file_put_contents('testlog.log',"\r\nFork Test",FILE_APPEND);
    return 1; //error
}
else if($pid){
    return 0; //success
}
else{   
    file_put_contents($log, 'Running...', FILE_APPEND);
}
```

I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pcntl_fork()
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: What's your OS? Be advised, that Windows has no underlying `*fork()` syscalls.

Comment: Have you successfully installed `php5-pcntl` ?

Comment: No I didn't realize that was something that needed to be installed separate from XAMPP.

Comment: It is. If you installed PHP via MacPorts try `port install php5-pcntl`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the XAMPP part. My bad.

Answer (score 33):

It is not possible to use the function 'pcntl_fork' when PHP is used as Apache module (such as XAMPP). You can only use pcntl_fork in CGI mode or from command-line.

Using this function will result in: `'Fatal error: Call to undefined function: pcntl_fork()'`

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: Adding to this, the OP should consider `curl_multi_exec` if running from a web page.

Answer (score 11):

To see if it is installed, run:

`php -i | grep pcntl`

If it is present and enabled then the pcntl function are likely disabled, which appears to be the default in newer PHP 5.x installs.  To check, run:

`php -i | grep disable_functions`

If you see a list of pcntl_* functions, you'll need to edit your php.ini file (inside of XAMPP) and comment out the line `disable_functions=`

I'd recommend you use [this distribution](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) of PHP for OS X, which has current versions and I can confirm does have the `pcntl` extension.

Comment: Commenting out "disabled_functions =" was a no go for me. #ubuntu1404 #php7.1

Comment: `disable_functions` return `warning` about security reason; neither `fatal` error about undefined function.

Answer (score 3):

`pcntl_*` functions, Process Control support in PHP is not enabled by default. You have to compile the CGI or CLI version (don't used as Apache module) of PHP with `--enable-pcntl` configuration option when compiling PHP to enable Process Control support.

Currently, this module will not function on **non-Unix platforms** (Windows).

[ref](http://php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when running the script as a part of Apache. So, my solution was to put the code containing `pcntl_fork` in a different file (let's call it `fork.php`) and use `exec()` to run it, like this:

mainFile.php (this is what Apache will run)

```
exec('php fork.php',$output);
```

fork.php

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if($pid == -1){
    file_put_contents('testlog.log',"\r\nFork Test",FILE_APPEND);
    return 1; //error
}
else if($pid){
    return 0; //success
}
else{   
    file_put_contents($log, 'Running...', FILE_APPEND);
}
```